# What's the word or phrase when one takes advantage of you but pretends and mocks you for thinking that way

Tags: single-word-requests

I saw someone posted this on Facebook and lot of people commented a **word/phrase** for that sort of situation. Basically someone does something to you but makes you think you are crazy in a sort of manipulative way. I can't find the post anywhere now and I forgot what word it is.

Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you mean *gaslighting*?

Comment: Oh yes! That's definitely it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for -

## Gaslight

> verb
> gerund or present participle: gaslighting
>
> : manipulate (someone) by psychological means into doubting their own
> sanity.

([From Lexico](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/gaslight))

---

**Edit**

I just realized this got mentioned in the comments. So I'll give credit to StoneyB.